# PHP command-line script - program usage text

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that takes to command line arguments.  I want the user to type the name of the program with no arguments:

```
$ ./foo.php
```

and I want it to output something like:

```
usage: $ ./foo arg1 arg2 where arg1 is something and arg2 is something else
```

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Many thanks :).

Comment: While this makes it less portable you might want to check out http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Getargs/ or similar helper libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just output it.

```
if (count($_SERVER['argv']) <= 1) {
  echo 'Usage: $ ' . $_SERVER['argv'][0] . ' arg1 arg2 where arg1 is something and arg2 is something else' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

`$_SERVER['argv']` contains all arguments from the command line and especially the first item is always the scriptname.

See ["reserved variables: $argv"](http://php.net/reserved.variables.argv) and ["reserved variables: $_SERVER"](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server). Note, that `$argv` is no available in any case, thus I recommend using `$_SERVER['argv']`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ARGV` to get these values from command line input.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php